# can't run docker login error is: Error saving credentials: error storing credentials

Tags: docker, authentication

I can login to docker desktop 
I can login to the GUI

The problem is that I can't login to docker via CLI so I can't pull/push images via my machine.

Docker Version

Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

I am on a mac running Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: what command did you use to login for CLI

Comment: docker login (then entered dockerhub username and password...I use these same passwords to login to the docker GUI, and the docker desktop apps without any issues

Comment: basically you lack administrator acess , try `sudo` if the OS is linuz based or try `running as administrator` if it is windos based

Answer (score 0):

I have your same configuration and the same happened to me this morning.  Logging in through the web worked, logging in through the docker desktop worked, but the CLI wouldn't log in and I received the same error about not being able to write the credentials.  Finally I decided to reboot to see if that would work... and it did.

I imagine a recent update might have messed up whatever interaction docker cli has with the macos keychain processes, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: thats not an answer

Comment: It certainly is an answer... and even better, it's a solution targeted for the platform/environment he clearly states in the question.

Answer (score -1):

`docker login -u 'yourusername'` should prompt you for your password. After entering the password you should be logged in.

Comment: tried that but still receive Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1....
some of the posts suggested 

Removing "credsStore": "osxkeychain" from ~/.docker/config.json I don't have that line in my config


cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
  "auths" : {

  },
  "credsStore" : "desktop",
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "experimental" : "disabled"
}

Others have said to try 

Deleting the file /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain

I tried this but it also didn't work...I have also uninstalled and reinstalled docker

Comment: Can you show the complete error log, well if it doesn't contain any sensitive information?

Comment: Password: 
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.``

Comment: As the error clearly says the username and passphrase is not correct, which means you have to be using the wrong username and password combination.